# Reused part of code in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, coffeescript

I have this code

`Template['product'].helpers(
  'variant': ->
    variant_value = Session.get('variant')
    if variant_value
      return variant_value
    else
      Session.set('variant',@lowest_variant())
  'isSelected': ->
    if @variant() == opt1_name
      return true
    else return false`

I want to used variant method inside isSelected. The code above does not work.  Any idea how  to create a function so that it can be used to different helper methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

but  *how to create a function so that it can be used to different helper methods*? **Just create a global function**

Im not an expert on coffee script.

but on meteor, this is what happened with global variables, from [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/coffeescript).

> Per the usual CoffeeScript convention, CoffeeScript variables are
>   file-scoped by default (visible only in the .coffee file where they
>   are defined.)

So you create that function at the top-level of the .coffee file you are using that helpers.

pure **javascript**

```
 variant = function(){  
     //code to be used on diferents helpers
    }
```

Comment: BTW to create global var in CoffeeScript: `@myGlobalVar = {}`, before you going to use it

Answer (score 0):

The reason you don't have access to your private helper method is that it is not created yet. It gets defined as part of the object that is returned to the `helpers()` method after its definition.

It has to be declared outside of that method:

```
variant = () ->
  variant_value = Session.get('variant')
  if variant_value
    return variant_value
  else
    Session.set('variant',@lowest_variant())

Template['product'].helpers(
  'isSelected': ->
    if variant() == opt1_name
      return true
    else return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think you're looking for `Template.registerHelper()` function

```
Template.registerHelper 'isSelected', ->
   return if variant() == opt1_name then true else false
```

Please, see docs [here](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_registerhelper)

**UPD:**
To create a global Meteor's app var in CoffeeScript just bind it to global scope via `@`:

```
@myGlobalVar = {}
```

Alternatively bind it to `Meteor` object:

```
Meteor.myGlobalVar = {}
```